# Formatting output of inline org-mode source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I want to include the output of inline code blocks in the LaTeX/PDF output of an org-mode document, but not in a monospaced font. I tried the following:

```
The mean petal length is src_R[:exports results :results raw]{mean(iris$Petal.Length)}.
```

which gives me this output in the LaTeX file:

```
The mean petal length is 3.758
.
```

The period in the sentence appears on a new line in the LaTeX file, which causes a space to appear between the code output and the period in the PDF.

[image]

Is there a way I can get the LaTeX output to appear all on one line so the PDF formatting is correct?

Comment: If this is a one-of thing, you could edit `ob-R.el` (and re-compile it, if you previously compiled it) by editing the function `org-babel-R-evaluate-external-process`, specifically, the place where it says `(buffer-string)`, replace it with `(org-trim (buffer-string))`. But I'm not sure how this will affect multiline results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to change the variable `org-babel-inline-result-wrap` from `=%s=`, which formats the output, to just `%s`, which does not.

You can do this with a non-exporting lisp code block somewhere in your file if you don't want to change it globally.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC lisp :exports none
  (setq org-babel-inline-result-wrap "%s")
#+END_SRC

This is a test of text: 4 and code: src_R{2+2}.
```

Comment: This worked! I changed `lisp` to `emacs-lisp` as the former wasn't working (probably I don't have slime set up correctly or something).